# How to add a new field to my entity in jhipster in 2021?

Tags: java, postgresql, jpa, jhipster, react-fullstack

I created a Jhipster project with postgres database and react frontend.  I want to add, edit and remove fields from only one entity.

What is the right procedure to do this ?  Last time I edited the JDL file and ran the application.  I ended up having a problem with liquibase (checksum match failure).  Is there a way to get this done properly every time I edit an entity ?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `--incremental-changelog` option to create an additionnal changelog for adding only the new field. This way, you won't modify existing one creating checksums differences.